# How do I use Espresso with System dialogs

Tags: android

I have buttons in my app that launch Android Chooser intents (ACTION_VIEW, etc.) And i was wondering how to use an Espresso idling resource. to wait and detect display of the dialog and how to cancel it and return after.

I am not asking for code per se .. just wondering how to do it?

e.g.

```
onView(withId(R.id.ad_email_button)).perform(click());
```

this button opens the intent

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
```

So how to cancel the dialog so the test doesn't hang and verify the appropriate system dialog was shown?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know using Espresso we are limited to actions and verifications inside specific Activity. But I found out that we can access UiAutomator as well and perform BACK action to dismiss alert dialog:

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation()
            .performGlobalAction(AccessibilityService.GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer is to use UIAutomator for these tests:
https://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#features